# How to add this CSS to Wordpress Posts to make into a Border-Box surrounding paragraphs? (Example)

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, plugins

Ok, here is the code I grabbed from http://MKVCage.com when checking out the source code, they are using the same WP theme as me, but are using the ***PRE*** as the 'class' for this, I wish to use something that is easy to insert from the 'Creating Post' section (I assume 'pre' worked for them):

```
pre {
    font-family:Open Sans;
    font-weight:400;
    display:block;
    font-size:13px;
    white-space:pre;
    white-space:pre-wrap;
    border:1px solid #ededed;
    background:#FCFCFC;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow:0 2px 5px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    line-height:22px;
    padding:8px 10px
    }
```

the original site: http://www.mkvcage.com
 My Site: http://tvepisodes.me

Both Wordpress Sites are using the free "heiro" theme

I wish to have the same 'boxes' that only present themselves on say when a certain TAG or CODE or shortcode is entered...Any help please.

I'm using PRE at the moment, but I noticed HTML/VISUAL is no longer available on WP Postings, does anyone know of a HTML Plugin that will bring the WYSIWYG/HTML tabs back please (request #2)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody, but I decided to go with the PRE tags in the post to accomplish this, as far as I can see with creating a whole new shortcode just for this, and the `<p>` tag is already taken for other normal paragraphs, I went with how mkvcage.com does it, maybe I will come back to it later...

For now It WORKS & I'm happy with the research & outcome so far!